# Partial sums of two dimensional array

Tags: java

I recieve a number n and then recieve n*n integers, representing a matrix, or an array of [n][n]. I want to create an array [n][n], where every cell contains the sum of all cells "left and above" from the original array, while not creating the array, just using the values.
For example, the cell [5][7], will contain the sum of the block [0][0] to [5][7] out of the original array.

I seriously need to simplify or speed up my code.

```
void read() {
    size = scan.nextInt();
    arrayLoad();
}

void arrayLoad() {
    area_values = new int [size][size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            add(scan.nextInt(),i,j);
        }
    }
}

void add(int num, int x, int y) {
    for (int i = x; i < size; i++) {
        for (int j = y; j < size; j++) {
            area_values[i][j] += num;
        }
    }
}
```

This is O(n^4), which, as you may be able to tell, is not exactly easy for n 4+ digits.

Comment: The first array in input using the scanner. The first number is the size of the array, which will be input.

Comment: Yes, but you say: `So, I have an array [n][n], which contains integers. I want to create a new array of the same size` ... I only see one array... are you building the array at the same times as adding it up?

Comment: I updated the question. I hope you understand my meaning now.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is an interesting problem. I think your solution will be possible and much, much faster if you [use memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization). This is the process where you remember your previous calculations and reuse them in your current calculations.

So, for example, suppose you process your array row-by-row.... if your input 2D array is:

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

And we were now processing the second row, and fourth column, our current result would look like (our current position is marked with a `?`):

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
2 4 6 ? 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Now, at that position, we know that the value will be 8 because we are human, and can see that. The best algorithm on the computer though, to get that 8, is that we can split the data we know in to 4 areas....

Consider the input data again (I have marked our spot with the parenthesis):

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1(1)1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

The 4 areas that we can think of as special are:

1. the value we are processing right now (the value `1`)
2. the column above the us (contains the values `[1]`)
3. the row we have processed so far (contains the values `[1, 1, 1]`)
4. the **rectangle** above-left of where we are so far (contains the value `[1, 1, 1]` as well)

Now, what is the sum of the values in the rectangle? We know that, because we have our grid right now which looks like:

```
1 2(3)4 5 6 7
2 4 6 ? 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

So, the rectangle from (0,0) to (0,2) has the sum `3` which has already been calculated (and which I have marked with parenthesis).

We have also calculated the sum of the data in the row to the left of us... look at the grid again:

```
1 2(3)4 5 6 7
2 4(6)? 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

The sum of the values in the row to the left is the difference between the rectangle above left, and the rectangle plain-left, or `6 - 3` == `3`.

Similarly, the sum of the values in the column above us, is the sum of the rectangle above us, less the rectangle above-left of us.

So, for any position in the solution matrix, the solution-sum of the values is:

1. the value at this point
2. plus the sum of all values above-left of us
3. plus the sum of all values above us
4. plus the sum of all values to the left.

Using a more convenient input format than the scanner, this can all be done in a single loop....

```
int[][] sumAboveLeft(int[] datasource) {
    if (datasource == null || datasource.length == 0 || datasource.length != datasource[0] * datasource[0] + 1) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    // first value in the source data is the matriz size
    final int size = datasource[0];
    // because the first value is the size, we expect the loop limit to be unusual.
    final int limit = datasource.length - 1;

    int[][] result = new int[size][size];

    for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
        // convert the linnear/flat address to a row/column
        int row = i / size;
        int col = i % size;

        // rectangle-sum above us
        int abovesum = row > 0 ? result[row - 1][col] : 0;
        // rectangle-sum to left of us
        int leftsum = col > 0 ? result[row][col - 1] : 0;
        // rectangle-sum above-left of us.
        int aboveleftsum = (col > 0 && row > 0) ? result[row - 1][col - 1] : 0;
        // our value at this point (note the index+1 offset because the first value is the size)
        int val = datasource[i + 1];
        // the sum here is
        // the value here
        // plus above-left-rectangle-sum
        // plus above-column-sum
        // plus left-row-sum
        result[row][col] = val
                         + aboveleftsum
                         + (leftsum - aboveleftsum)
                         + (abovesum - aboveleftsum);
    }
    return result;

}
```

I have put a lot of comments in there for you...

I have also tested it with:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(sumAboveLeft(new int[]{
         7,
         1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
         1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
         1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
         1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
         1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
         1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
         1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
    })));
}
```

So, the process can be done in *O(n)*, where n is the number of members in the matrix.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was stuck for a long time and you have made it so clear. Thank you for taking the time to educate a newbie, such as myself.